# Casting error in ADO.NET Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am very new to EF and trying to populate data on textbox on combobox change event using ADO.NET EF. I tried parsing everything but error exists all the time. My code is given below....
Please help me....Thanks in advance.

```
private List<tSubDepartment> GetSubDepartmentInfo(int deptId)
    {
        using (DiagnosoftDataContext context = new DiagnosoftDataContext())
        {
            return (from c in context.tSubDepartments
                    where c.dpCode == deptId
                    select c).ToList();
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var subDeptInfo =GetDepartmentInfo((int)comboBox1.SelectedValue);   // Error: "Specific cast is not valid"
        textBox2.Text = subDeptInfo[0].sdCode.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = subDeptInfo[0].sdName;
        textBox4.Text = subDeptInfo[0].dpCode.ToString();

    }
```

Here is my code to populate combobox

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = GetSubDepartments();
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "sdName";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "sdCode";
    }

private List<tSubDepartment> GetSubDepartments()
    {
        using (DiagnosoftDataContext context = new DiagnosoftDataContext())
        {
            return (from c in context.tSubDepartments select c).ToList();

        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried ClickBright and Joe Enos advice but it is not working yet...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's got nothing to do with EF. My guess is your values in your combobox are strings, not integers. So you can try

```
int.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedValue)
```

instead of

```
(int)comboBox1.SelectedValue
```

If that doesn't work, then you've probably got something else in there - take a look at what kind of object `comboBox1.SelectedValue` is - it can be anything. That's what you'd need to cast it to, then work with the object from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                int x = int.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

                var subDeptInfo =GetDepartmentInfo(x);   
                textBox2.Text = subDeptInfo[0].sdCode.ToString();
                textBox3.Text = subDeptInfo[0].sdName;
                textBox4.Text = subDeptInfo[0].dpCode.ToString();
            }
            else { //Value is null }
```